# Plot order of annotations changes with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I create a bar plot using `ggplot` with several annotations of the form `rect`. I do it such that the annotations are behind the bars in the plot. When I convert the plot using `ggplotly`, the annotations appear in front of the bars. Is there a way that I can preserve the order of plotting using ggplotly? Or can I change the order after the ggplotly conversion?

```
name = c("Phil", "Ian", "Leslie", "Darla", "Silvia", "Ron", "Emily", "Jack")
score = c(10, 12, 15, 30, 35, 40, 55.2, 75)
test1 <- data.frame(name, score)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plt <- ggplot(test1, aes(x=name, y=score)) +
  
  scale_x_discrete() +
  
  annotate("rect", xmin=0, xmax=9, ymin=0, ymax=20, fill="#2eb82e", alpha=0.4) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=0, xmax=9, ymin=20, ymax=50, fill="#ff0000", alpha=0.4) +
  
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

ggplotly(plt)
```

Desired behaviour using ggplot
[image: Desired behaviour using ggplot]

Plotting order changes when converted using ggplotly
[image: Plotting order changes when converted using ggplotly]

Comment: have you tried this using `geom_rect` instead of annotate?

Comment: I changed the code to use geom_rect as follows: `geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 9, ymin = 0, ymax = 20), fill = "#2eb82e",alpha=0.4) +` and `geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 9, ymin = 20, ymax = 50), fill = "#ff0000",alpha=0.4) +`. Oddly I also have to make the following change to make it respect the opacity `geom_bar(data=test1, aes(x=name, y=score), stat="identity")`. However, the same behaviour persists unfortunately.

Comment: I tried changing the layer order on the `ggplot` object but it didn't change plotly! This didn't work neither `pltly <- ggplotly(plt); pltly$x$layout$shapes[[1]]$layer="below"` I wrote an answer using `plot_ly`

Comment: Thanks @Vida I have played around with that in various ways and couldn't get it to work. The problem here is that `ggplotly` converts the `geon_rect`/`annotate` objects to filled scatter traces so they aren't stored as shapes. scatter traces don't seem to have a `layer` option.

Comment: That's right, they aren't shapes, the closest I could get to your plot is by `plot_ly` that I posted, could you try that?

Comment: Yes I did, and thank you very much for that. I Added a reply below.

Comment: I just saw that and your solution, great idea, I didn't think about adding the shapes to your `ggplotly` object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the end that still creates plot in `ggplot` but adds the shapes after the fact using `plotly` by manually editing the `plotly_plot` structure. I would still prefer it if I could do it all in ggplot but I think that it isn't possible when converting with ggplotly:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

name = c("Phil", "Ian", "Leslie", "Darla", "Silvia", "Ron", "Emily", "Jack")
score = c(10, 12, 15, 30, 35, 40, 55.2, 75)
test1 <- data.frame(name, score)

plt <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=test1, aes(x=name, y=score), stat="identity")

plotly_plot <- ggplotly(plt)

# Turn off the grid or else it shows over the top of the 
plotly_obj$x$layout$xaxis$showgrid <- FALSE
plotly_obj$x$layout$yaxis$showgrid <- FALSE

# Add the shapes to the plotly object
plotly_obj$x$layout$shapes <- list(list(type = 'rect', 
                                        x0 = 0, x1 = 9, xref = "x", 
                                        y0 = 0, y1 = 20, yref = "y", 
                                        fillcolor = "#2eb82e", 
                                        opacity  = 0.4,
                                        layer = 'below'),
                                   list(type = 'rect', 
                                        x0 = 0, x1 = 9, xref = "x", 
                                        y0 = 20, y1 = 50, yref = "y",
                                        fillcolor = "#ff0000", 
                                        opacity  = 0.4,
                                        layer = 'below'))

# Make the line colours the same as the fill colour...there must be a simple way to add this to the code above as well.
plotly_obj$x$layout$shapes[[1]]$line$color <- "#2eb82e"
plotly_obj$x$layout$shapes[[2]]$line$color <- "#ff0000"

plotly_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `plot_ly`

```
shapes <- list(
  list(type = "rect",
       fillcolor = "#2eb82e",
       x0 = -1, x1 = 8, xref = "x",
       y0 = 0.0, y1 = 20, yref = "y",
       line = list(width=0),
       opacity = 0.5, layer="below"),
  list(type = "rect",
       fillcolor = "#ff0000",
       x0 = -1, x1 = 8, xref = "x",
       y0 = 20, y1 = 50, yref = "y",
       line = list(width=0),
       opacity = 0.5, layer="below")
)
plot_ly() %>%
  layout(shapes = shapes) %>%
  add_bars(x = name,
           y = score,
           marker = list(color = 'grey'))
```

read for more options https://plotly.com/r/shapes/

Comment: Thank you very much for your work on this @Vida. and this does indeed provide the correct desired output. However, the code I have supplied above is a very simple reprex. In reality I need to do this to many plots which are already being generated in ggplot and I am trying to avoid rewriting them in plotly completely. In retrospect, that might have been the easier option.